# How to fix distortion coefficients to 0 during OpenCV's calibrateCamera?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning about OpenCV's calibrateCamera function and trying to fix distortion coefficients to 0 as I don't want to take distortion into account for now.

```
    # reprojection error, calibration matrix, distortion, rotation and translation vectors
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(
        [3d_points.astype(np.float32)], 
        [image_points.astype(np.float32)], 
        (img_raw.shape[1], img_raw.shape[0]), None, distCoeffs = np.zeros((5, 1),dtype=np.float32))
```

However, in the output I still get non-zero dist coefficients

```
dist
array([[-0.06402103],
       [ 0.76996236],
       [ 0.05764124],
       [ 0.02921579],
       [-1.12958531]])
```

How do I fix them so it doesn't try to optimize them?

Comment: explore the available flags. see anything good?

Comment: Hey there, as I mentioned I'm learning OpenCV and if you know the correct flag you could just write it. But to answer your question, as a matter of fact, I did explore various flags. They have various flags to fix specific type of distortion or distortion coefficients as dirtotion can be of different origin. But I don't see one flag that stops all distortion types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the different flags together, like `flag=cv2.CALIB_FIX_K1+cv2.CALIB_FIX_K2+cv2.CALIB_FIX_K3+cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST`

I believe by default, OpenCV only gives [k1 k2 p1 p2 k3] so it should be sufficient to fix these ones.